# Feature Request: Accept rate for mobile site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, accept-rate

I, and I think some other people, would really appreciate to see the accept rate in the mobile site of SO. To me the accept rate immediately indicates whether i should answer the question or not even think about it. It would probably be a waste of time to answer a question of somebody who doesn't care about voting, accepting or even reading your answer. I think a simple `xxx%` in green next to the avatar would do it.

Comment: Rats, it's 100 now! That was quick. :)

Comment: lol i didn't even read your comment^^ Oh and i only have two questions here, one old, accepted question, and this obe was still open so I didn't yet decide which answer to accept! And i was talking about SO not meta in my question, on SO ive got clean 100% (i think)

Comment: yeah. I was kidding - just to point out that the accept rate is an imperfect way of telling how deserving of answers a user is :)

Comment: Haha you're so right!

Comment: Declined as [accept rate is no longer shown with on the usercard for a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say has validity - someone who doesn't care enough to accept good answers to their questions may not be "deserving" of future help. However, there are people who are happy to just answer the question without worrying about whether their answers will be accepted or not. Seeing the corpus of knowledge increase can be a reward in and of itself.

However, there's no right or wrong answer - it's all subjective.

Answer (score 3):

Given the fact that many mobile devices require a bit of 'extra effort' when crafting a well written answer, I'd say this is a good idea. If you want to spend your away from PC time being helpful on the site, I think it's fair to let you skip to questions that you feel good about answering.

However, I would caution against making an accept rate such a deciding factor. If the question is interesting and you can nail it, enjoy hitting the mortarboard and don't worry about the last fifteen points.

Going over the accept rate problem repeatedly in my head, the only way to solve the issue is to remove the +15 bonus that acceptance provides. I don't think anyone wants to do that and have yet another re-calc, so we may as well just deal with it while encouraging people to focus on the question *first*.

There are just some parts of human nature that we can't program around. This is one of them (imho).