# Commenting on user Question like : increase your accept rate first

Tags: discussion, comments, accept-rate

I am seeing this type of comment every now and then when any user or say New User have posted a question. recenltly seen in **[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337746/how-to-remove-listview-margin)**

Here there is a comment and You can see that comment got upvote and the Question got downvote..Why?
I don't see any valid reason..cause in that case The user have asked only 2 Question.

Yes it's true that while answering to any question one would see to the Accept Rate and some time get disappoint with low accept rate of user.

But According to a new SO user..when he/she gets comment like this rather than any related answer or related comment,becomes disappointment for asker.

My Questions are :
1) One should really comment like this?(yes if user is new..might be not aware to the feature but if the user have only asked 2-3 questions then?)

2) Don't you think this type of comments disappoint the user who is stuck in a problem and finiding solution.

3) Giving down-votes to the question whoes user has low accept rate..what's the point in that?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110645/132734

Comment: I think the "accept rate police" is really just another stage of a user's development, somewhere between "new user" and "seasoned contributor."

Comment: @David I think the same

Answer (score 7):

I nuked the comment* =)  The user has to ask at least 4 questions to even *have* an accept rate!

Putting comments like that, without a link to [the post on here about accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/168428), is not helpful in any way.  Many new users won't even understand what it means without any context.

So in answer to your questions:

1. Sometimes, but always be respectful.  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23326/168428) for a good explanation.
2. Sure it's disappointing.  Especially if they don't understand these off-topic, out-of-context references to "Accept Rate".
3. From the post I referenced in 1,

   NO, it is not appropriate to change your behaviour because of some user's acceptance rate.

*One flag on a comment about "Accept Rate" will usually delete it automatically ([reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104362/168428))

Comment: Useful to who don't even know : The user has to ask at least 4 questions to even have an accept rate..yes One should pass the link for what is accept rate!