# What to do when OP thanks but does not accept any answer?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

If you provide a good answer for a question and the asker explicitly comment your answer with something like: "*Thanks so much, now it's working!*", but he **does not accept** your answer (maybe because it's a newbie with 1 rep and just doesn't know how to do it)... what should you do?

I understand the first option is to kindly ask him to accept your answer... but, if even so your answer isn't accepted... you just have to put up with it, right?

Comment: Related: [Comments saying "thank you" remind OP to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177292)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do anything. Nobody has to accept an answer. Nor can you make him to. Just move on.

And you don't need to "remind" him to accept an answer. New users get the tour.

Comment: I think it's pretty okay to leave a comment when OP just seems ignorant.  When you throw 13 things in the tour it's not like they're going to remember or take notes on the complete workflow.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110645/172011

Comment: That's not the same as a polite _"Hi I notice you're new to Stack Exchange, if any one of the answers to this question solved your problem for you then please consider accepting it (some link). This is in no way obligatory and should only be done if your question has been solved"_ @juergend. If someone's bugging you then, yes, flag, if it's their first ever question then a polite reminder is fine (especially if you remember to delete the comment afterwards :-).

Comment: Thanks, I disagree though and commented there - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/comment-regarding-accept-rate-removed/110645#comment562480_110645

Comment: +1. No checkmark begging. It's just poor taste. Flag that noise.